# Jupyterhub with custom singleuser image raises 'no such file or directory' for '/home/jovyan/work'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pytorch, jupyterhub

I tried to setup Jupyterhub to serve Jupyter pytorch notebook using this repo as image `https://github.com/stepankuzmin/pytorch-notebook`, which is also available as a Docker image on dockerhub as `https://hub.docker.com/r/stepankuzmin/pytorch-notebook/`.

This involves modifying the config.yml file to point to the image, e.g.:

`singleuser:
  image:
    name: stepankuzmin/pytorch-notebook
    tag: latest`

I am getting:

`oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"chdir to cwd (\\\"/home/jovyan/work\\\") set in config.json failed: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

After much googling I stumbled on this: https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/1425. The summary from this is thread is the error can occur due to:
* The singleuser jupyterhub image you are building does not conform to the requirements
* You are building a singleuser jupyterhub image based on an old base image of singleuser jupyter

The only way for me to proceed was to build my own singleuser jupyterhub pytorch jupyter notebook image, which is now available here: https://hub.docker.com/r/nethsix/pytorch-notebook/

The repo is: https://github.com/nethsix/pytorch-notebook

I built the image using repo2docker as documented here: http://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-environment.html#build-a-custom-docker-image-with-repo2docker